Headline references in org-mode export with custom link type
I want to use an org-mode custom link type x: for referring to headlines. The purpose is to add some special formatting to the exported cross-references. The initial target is LaTeX export.
However, I can't figure out how to get hold of the right references (trying to use org-export-get-reference). Here is my non-working code:
(defun org-get-headings ()
  "Return an alist of all headings in the current buffer with their positions."
  (let (headings)
    (org-map-entries
     (lambda ()
       (push (cons (org-get-heading t t t t) (point)) headings)))
    (nreverse headings)))

(org-link-set-parameters
 "x"
 :export (lambda (path desc backend info)
           (cond
            ((eq backend 'latex)
             (let* ((headings (org-get-headings))
                    (match (assoc path headings)))
               (if match
                   (let ((pos (cdr match)))
                     (save-excursion
                       (goto-char pos)
                       (let* ((headline (org-element-at-point))
                              (reference (org-export-get-reference headline info)))
                         (format "xtra special! \\hyperref[%s]{%s}"
                                 reference
                                 (or desc path)))))
                 (format "Missing heading: %s" path))))
            (t (or desc path)))))

When applied to the following org content,
* Alfred

[[Alfred]]

x:Alfred

x:nada

The exported LaTeX does include a reference for the x:Alfred link, but it's not the right one. The built-in link using [[Alfred]] works correctly.
\section{Alfred}
\label{sec:orgf560594}

\ref{sec:orgf560594}

xtra special! \hyperref[org8bf805b]{Alfred}

Missing heading: nada


https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Well, I'm not trying to show excellent Elisp here. It's not straightforward to see how the info context can be accessed for custom links "in context". Have searched and looked into the org libraries, but without success.

If you are referring to @Drew's excision of the elisp tag, the quality of the code is not the point. The point is that the elisp tag should almost never be used: it has a very special meaning as described in the link that @Drew posted and that meaning does not apply to most questions (including this one).

Ah, sorry about that, I admit I didn't check beforehand!

NP - it's a common misunderstanding, so the sooner it is caught, the better for all of us.
